# SQL count number of rows in unique combinations of key value columns

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-by, pivot

Given the following MySQL table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `order_params`( `order_id` BIGINT(30) NOT NULL, 
              `key` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, `value` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL );
```

And this data:

```
INSERT INTO `order_params` (`order_id`, `key`, `value`) VALUES ('1', 'browser', 'Firefox'); 
INSERT INTO `order_params` (`order_id`, `key`, `value`) VALUES ('1', 'os', 'Windows'); 
INSERT INTO `order_params` (`order_id`, `key`, `value`) VALUES ('2', 'browser', 'Firefox'); 
INSERT INTO `order_params` (`order_id`, `key`, `value`) VALUES ('2', 'os', 'Windows'); 
INSERT INTO `order_params` (`order_id`, `key`, `value`) VALUES ('3', 'browser', 'Firefox'); 
INSERT INTO `order_params` (`order_id`, `key`, `value`) VALUES ('3', 'os', 'OSX'); 
INSERT INTO `order_params` (`order_id`, `key`, `value`) VALUES ('4', 'browser', 'Safari'); 
INSERT INTO `order_params` (`order_id`, `key`, `value`) VALUES ('4', 'os', 'OSX'); 
INSERT INTO `order_params` (`order_id`, `key`, `value`) VALUES ('5', 'browser', 'Safari'); 
INSERT INTO `order_params` (`order_id`, `key`, `value`) VALUES ('5', 'os', 'OSX'); 
INSERT INTO `order_params` (`order_id`, `key`, `value`) VALUES ('5', 'version', '5');
```

How do I get the following results?

```
browser Firefox os Windows              2
browser Firefox os OSX                  1
browser Safari os OSX                   1
browser Safari os OSX version 5         1
```

The numbers on the right are the count of records that match the unique key/value combinations.  Is this even possible?

OK, updating to show that I have tried this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(`key`, `value`), COUNT(*)
FROM order_params 
GROUP BY `order_id`, `key`, `value`;
```

And this is the result:

```
browserFirefox  1
osWindows       1
browserFirefox  1
osWindows       1
browserFirefox  1
osOS X          1
browserSafari   1
osOS X          1
```

I've also tried this:

```
SELECT `key`, `value`, COUNT(*)
FROM order_params 
GROUP BY `key`, `value`;
```

Which produces this:

```
browser Firefox  3
browser Safari   1
os OS X          2
os Windows       2
```

Obviously, neither of these is the desired result.

Comment: Please try and come with doubts.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is two stages of aggregation

```
select browser, os, version, count(*)
from (select order_id,
             max(case when `key` = 'browser' then `value` end) as browser,
             max(case when `key` = 'os' then `value` end) as os,
             max(case when `key` = 'version' then `value` end) as version
      from order_params op
      group by order_id
     ) p
group by browser, os, version
```

If you actually want the string that you have, you can concat things together:

```
select concat(coalesce(concat('browser ', browser), ''),
              coalesce(concat('os ', os), ''),
              coalesce(concat('version ', version), ''), count(*)
from (select order_id,
             max(case when `key` = 'browser' then `value` end) as browser,
             max(case when `key` = 'os' then `value` end) as os,
             max(case when `key` = 'version' then `value` end) as version
      from order_params op
      group by order_id
     ) p
group by os, browser, version
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  So I can only do this if I know the keys ahead of time, and code it into my SQL statement?  I was hoping to do it for N number of keys.

Comment: What you're looking for is a "pivot" operator, which mysql doesn't have. If you search the site for "mysql pivot" you'll find many workarounds.

Comment: Thanks.  This doesn't look as fun as I thought it would be.  I'm going to flatten the data model for this table and just use fixed columns rather than deal with pivoting every time I want to run a query.